# Replacing only a specific group within a matched expression

Tags: python, regex

I'm parsing text in which I would like to make changes, but only to specific lines.

I have a regular expression pattern that catches the entire line if it's a line of interest, and within the expression I have a remembered group of the thing I would actually like to change.

I would like to be able to changed only the specific group within a matched expression, and not replace the entire expression (that would replace the entire line).

For example:

I have a textual file with:

```
This is a completely silly example.
something something "this should be replaced" bla.
more uninteresting stuff
```

And I have the regex: 
`pattern = '.*("[^"]*").*'`

Then I catch the second line, but I would to replace only the `"this should be replaced"` matched group within the line, not the entire line. (so using `re.sub(pattern, replacement, string)` won't do the job.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

What's wrong with

```
r'"[^"]+"'
```

Your `.*` before and after the matched expression match zero-length-string too, so you don't need it at all.

```
re.sub(r'"[^"]+"', 'DEF', 'abc"def"ghi')
# returns 'abcDEFghi'
```

and your example text will result into:

```
'This is a completely silly example.\nsomething something DEF bla.\nmore uninteresting stuff
```

Answer (score 2):

eumiro answer is best in this very case, but for the sake of completeness, if you really need to perform some more complicated processing of pre, inside, and post text, you can simply use multiple groups, like:

```
'(.*)("[^"]*")(.*)'
```

(first group provides the the text before, third the text after, do what you like with them)

Also, you may prefer to forbid " in the pre-part:

```
'([^"]*)("[^"]*")(.*)'
```

Comment: You can't use substitutions on select though.

Answer (score 2):

`re.match` and `re.search` return a "match object". (See the python documentation). Supposing you want to replace group 3 in your RE, pull out its start/end indices and replace the substring directly:

```
mobj = re.match(pattern, line)
start = mobj.start(3)
end = mobj.end(3)
line = line[:start] + replacement + line[end:]
```